# Replace a special character in a regular expression using that /g

Tags: javascript, regex, query-string

I'm getting from a query param, a string that contains escaped spaces, with something that looks like this "I+have+to+go".

I'm using the replace function to do that.

```
'I+have+to+go'.replace('+',' ') // Gives I have+to+go
'I+have+to+go'.replace(/+/g, '') // Doesn't work ! Probably because + is a
```

Special character of JavaScript regular expressions.

So is there a solution to escape + in the regular expression.

Answer (score -1):

This works.

```
console.log('I+have+to+go'.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
```